# Is it possible to determine motion/speed of a "moving object" with a "moving camera "?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on my FYP [ AI for visually impaired ] & I have recently been assigned to measure speed of a moving object with a moving camera [ I.e The person is walking ], I was wondering if is it possible? All the tutorials or papers I have seen so far show the procedure with the help of a static camera and all previous questions seems to be unanswered. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "The person is walking"so is the object you want to recognize a person? Or is the camera held by a walking person? What object do you want to track?
Does the camera and the object move in the same general direction?
Do you need to tell the exact speed in mph or kmh or is an uncalibrated number enough.

Comment: @NicolasGervais this task was assigned by my supervisor.
I was supposed to do this task in two weeks.

Comment: @DavidSalb let's put it in this way that the person "X" is walking on the road and YOLO detects an object/ or an object is detected using any method on the specified portion of the frame[i.e constraint] . My system [specified task ] should be able to detect the course of its motion of that object so that the person "X" can avoid it if the system detects the course of motion is towards you and there is a choice of collision between X and the object. 
1: Camera is held by the walking person.
2: Objects detected by YOLO/Any algorithm.
3: In opposite direction.
4: A rough number for starters

Comment: Let's skip the number to make it easier and detemine whether the person is moving towards the person "X" or moving away from the person based on pixel displacement.

Comment: your supervisor probably has no idea how difficult this is, so i suggest you explain him.

Comment: A general approach could be optical KLT flow to determine if the intersection of the displacement vectors is on your object. This can give you a general indication when the camera is moving towards the object. I would encourage you to try and tinker with it. But much more is required to actually determine the speed.